# GPS jump/ bad Location

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, location

I am a developer for android app. I wrote a location based program in kotlin android and see bad location on some devices. you can see this image and I will explain it right now

[jum location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1msrG.png)

In the photo, you can see that the user is in a wrong place, but in a few seconds, the correct location is sent.

I used fused or gps, but both have this problem.
you can see a photo of all users who have this problem.

[all bad locations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qeAn.png)

When does the speed = 0.0277777798473835 and the accuracy=1 happen? Why do all users who are in different places have such a problem and have the same speed and accuracy? Why?
Has anyone faced such a problem?
When does this problem appear?